# Download Word/Doc file code not working in IE8

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

here i download a word/doc file using row command event of grid click and i write a method downloadresume. this method is working fine in all browser except internet explorer in IE its generate .aspx rather than file.can any one help me to out this issue

```
protected void grdCandidate_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
            byte[] Attachment = null;
            string Extension = string.Empty;
            ClsCandidateManager objCandidateManager = new ClsCandidateManager();
            Attachment = objCandidateManager.GetCandidateAttachment(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument), out Extension);
            DownloadAttachment("Resume", Attachment, Extension);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string str = ex.Message + ex.InnerException;

    }
}

public void DownloadAttachment(string strFileName, byte[] Attachment, string Extension)
{
    if (Attachment != null && Attachment.Length > 0)
    {
        Page.Response.Clear();
        Page.Response.Buffer = true;
        Page.Response.Charset = "";
        if (Extension == ".pdf")
        {
            Page.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        }
        else
        {
            Page.Response.ContentType = "application/vsd-msword";
        }
        Page.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + strFileName + Extension);

        Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Page.Response.BinaryWrite(Attachment);
        Page.Response.Flush();
        //Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Attachment", "alert('Attachment not found!');", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Enable 'File Download' option in 'Security' tab in Internet Options to download the file from browser.
Check link for downloading Word/Doc files from IE - http://ais-ss.usc.edu/helpdoc/main/browser/bris004b.html

Comment: hi user2323308, i have set the functionality but still not working

Comment: Same code is working on my side. When I click, I get option with Open, Save and SaveAs with dialog box in IE. After changing the settings in IE, have you restared the IE?

Comment: ya restart in IE but it still giving .aspx page not actual file